# Cannot render base 64 in a img tag on React page

Tags: reactjs

This is my Flask API which is sending the data to React frontend:

```html
@app.route("/api/newface", methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def get_user_face():
    image_str = request.files.get('faceImage').read()
    image_np = np.fromstring(image_str, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(image_np, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    result = run(img)
    return result
```

And I got this response:

```html
{data: "�PNG↵↵��5���sBIT|d�, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Then I convert it into base64 and store it in my state:

```html
const b64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.data)));
this.setState({faceImage: b64, isLoaded: true})
```

And I got:

```html
{faceImage: "77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAAC77+9AAAB77+9CAYAAAA177…vv71/AO+/vQBk77+9RmQk77+9AAAAAElFTkTvv71CYO+/vQ==", isLoaded: true}
```

When I tried to render it, there is nothing on the page:

```html
<div>
   <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.faceImage}`} alt=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your base 64 is wrong. this part unescape(encodeURIComponent seems unecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
@app.route("/api/newface", methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def get_user_face():
    img_file = request.files['faceImage']
    f = img_file.stream.read()
    bin_data = io.BytesIO(f)
    file_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(bin_data.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    img = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res_img = run(gray_img)
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', res_img)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    return Response(response=jpg_as_text, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript [FileReader readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) Method to parse your blob to base64.

```html
var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e) => { 
                  var b64 =  e.target.result;
                  this.setState({faceImage: b64, isLoaded: true})
              }
reader.readAsDataURL(response.data)
```

Comment: I tried, and it says: DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
    at axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.post.then.response (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:281:21)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to encode the image in Flask and it works.